# Get ACF Custom Field value from page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I feel like this has an obvious answer, but I’ve yet to find it. I have a few custom fields bound to a page type, but I’m unsure how to retrieve the value of these fields in my template. All resources reference `the_field()` and/or `get_post_meta()`, but both of these are for posts, not pages. Any advice?

Comment: These functions work for pages, too. Pages are just another post type in WordPress.

Comment: @cabrerahector Hmm, so if I would normally get a post custom field value by `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_link', true)`, how would I get the ID of the page? By `get_the_ID()`?

Comment: The same way: `$post->ID` will give you the page ID. As I pointed out earlier `page` is just a different type of `post`, WordPress just uses `$post` to represent all post types - including pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this Is what I found out.
So firstly you must get the ID of your page.

$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

after that, you can pass it to get_fields();

$fields=get_fields($page_for_posts);

this will give you all of the information about the page.

There may be a better solution but this is what I came up with